# Embed DocuSign Signing Experience in a .NET Application

Tags: asp.net, iframe, docusignapi

I am working in a .NET Web Application(Web Forms).I need to embed the document signing experience into my web application,preferably by means of an Iframe.

Is is possible to authenticate to docusign from the web application and then bring the signing experience in an Iframe?

Also is it possible to re-direct to a custom URL on signing complete,signing declined,window closed..etc?

Comment: Isn't better the company that provide that "DocuSign eSignature" to give that answer and solution ?

Comment: @Aristos: I have tagged docusign in question.

Comment: We are doing this, and suddenly on iOS, we are having issues in the iFrame (Possibly a CORS issue).  DocuSign support says they don't support iFrame.  So doing the actual redirect seems like the proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a copy of the API walkthrough on how to do embedded signing in C#.  You can find other walkthroughs here: http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthroughs.

The code below should do exactly what you are looking for - give you an authenticated IFRAME ready for signing.  Before using this you should create a template with your document and place the signature tabs in the places where you want someone to sign.

```
// DocuSign API Walkthrough 08 in C# - Embedded Signing

// To run this sample: 
//  1) Create a new .NET project.
//  2) Add 3 assembly references to the project:  System, System.Net, and System.XML
//  3) Update the username, password, integrator key, and templateId in the code
//  4) Compile and Run
//
using System; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;

namespace APIWalkthrough08 
{
    public class EmbeddedSigning
    {
        // Enter your info:
        static string username = "***";
        static string password = "***";
        static string integratorKey = "***";
        static string templateId = "***";
        static string roleName = "***";

        public static void Main ()
        {
            string url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
            string baseURL = "";    // we will retrieve this
            string accountId = "";  // will retrieve
            string envelopeId = ""; // will retrieve
            string uri = "";    // will retrieve

            string authenticateStr = 
                "<DocuSignCredentials>" + 
                    "<Username>" + username + "</Username>" +
                    "<Password>" + password + "</Password>" + 
                    "<IntegratorKey>" + integratorKey + "</IntegratorKey>" + 
                    "</DocuSignCredentials>";

            // 
            // STEP 1 - Login
            //
            try {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (url);
                request.Headers.Add ("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
                request.Accept = "application/xml";
                request.Method = "GET";
                HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(responseText))) {
                    while (reader.Read()) { // Parse the xml response body
                        if((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "accountId"))
                            accountId = reader.ReadString();
                        if((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "baseUrl"))
                            baseURL = reader.ReadString();
                    }
                }

                //--- display results
                Console.WriteLine("accountId = " + accountId + "\nbaseUrl = " + baseURL);

                //
                // STEP 2 - Request Envelope Result
                //

                // Construct an outgoing XML request body
                string requestBody = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" + 
                    "<accountId>" + accountId + "</accountId>" + 
                        "<status>sent</status>" + 
                        "<emailSubject>API Call for Embedded Sending</emailSubject>" + 
                        "<emailBlurb>This comes from C#</emailBlurb>" + 
                        "<templateId>" + templateId + "</templateId>" + 
                        "<templateRoles>" + 
                        "<templateRole>" + 
                        "<email>" + username + "</email>" + // NOTE: Use different email address if username provided in non-email format!
                        "<name>Name</name>" +               // username can be in email format or an actual ID string
                        "<roleName>" + roleName + "</roleName>" +
                        "<clientUserId>1</clientUserId>" +
                        "</templateRole>" + 
                        "</templateRoles>" + 
                        "</envelopeDefinition>";

                // append "/envelopes" to baseUrl and use in the request
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (baseURL + "/envelopes");
                request.Headers.Add ("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
                request.ContentType = "application/xml";
                request.Accept = "application/xml";
                request.ContentLength = requestBody.Length;
                request.Method = "POST";
                // write the body of the request
                byte[] body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (requestBody);
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
                dataStream.Write (body, 0, requestBody.Length);
                dataStream.Close ();
                // read the response
                webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(responseText))) {
                    while (reader.Read()) { // Parse the xml response body
                        if((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "envelopeId"))
                            envelopeId = reader.ReadString();
                        if((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "uri"))
                            uri = reader.ReadString();
                    }
                }

                //--- display results
                Console.WriteLine("Envelope sent!.  EnvelopeId is --> " + envelopeId);

                //
                // STEP 3 - Get the Embedded Console Sign View
                //

                // construct another outgoing XML request body
                string reqBody = "<recipientViewRequest xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">"  +
                    "<authenticationMethod>email</authenticationMethod>" + 
                        "<email>" + username + "</email>" +     // NOTE: Use different email address if username provided in non-email format!
                        "<returnUrl>http://www.docusign.com</returnUrl>" +  // username can be in email format or an actual ID string
                        "<clientUserId>1</clientUserId>" + 
                        "<userName>Name</userName>" + 
                        "</recipientViewRequest>";

                // append uri + "/views/recipient" to baseUrl and use in the request
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (baseURL + uri + "/views/recipient");
                request.Headers.Add ("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
                request.ContentType = "application/xml";
                request.Accept = "application/xml";
                request.ContentLength = reqBody.Length;
                request.Method = "POST";
                // write the body of the request
                byte[] body2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (reqBody);
                Stream dataStream2 = request.GetRequestStream ();
                dataStream2.Write (body2, 0, reqBody.Length);
                dataStream2.Close ();
                // read the response
                webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(responseText))) {
                    while (reader.Read()) { // Parse the xml response body
                        if((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "url"))
                            url = reader.ReadString();
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Embeded View Result --> " + responseText);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
            }
            catch (WebException e) {
                using (WebResponse response = e.Response) {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                    using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(text);
                    }
                }
            }
        } // end main()
    } // end class
} // end namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, I'd suggest that you review the DocuSign REST API Guide: http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf -- as it contains all the information you need to accomplish your goals (in greater detail than I'll describe here).

To create/send an Envelope via the REST API, you'll use `POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes`, as described in the "**Send an Envelope or Create a Draft Envelope**" section of the API guide.  For each recipient whom you'll want to sign embedded/captive within your application, be sure to set the **clientUserId** property for the recipient -- the presence of this property for a recipient in the Create Envelope request is what tells DocuSign that your application will be initiating/facilitating the signing experience for the Recipient (so DocuSign won't send a signing invitation email to the Recipient).

When it's time for the Recipient to view/sign the Envelope within your application, you'll use `POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient`, as described in the "**POST Recipient View**" section of the API guide -- to retrieve a URL that can be used to launch/initiate the Recipient's DocuSign signing session. Using this URL as the target of an iFrame will present the DocuSign signing session within the frame. In the **POST Recipient View** request, you set the **returnUrl** property to indicate where DocuSign should redirect the signer when their embedded/captive signing session is complete.  DocuSign will append a querystring parameter ("event") when redirecting to this URL, and the value of that parameter will indicate the outcome of the Signing session. The **returnUrl** parameter description on page 167 of the API guide lists the possible values of this parameter. Your application (i.e., the redirect page you specify) can interrogate this parameter value to know the outcome of the signing session, and take whatever action is necessary.

Regarding authentication -- the information used to authenticate the Sender of the Envelope is supplied via the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header of each API request. Additionally, a specific form of authentication can be specified for each Recipient -- for example, Access Code, Phone Authentication, ID Check, SMS Auth -- you can specify authentication method for each Recipient by setting the appropriate properties for each Recipient in the "Create Envelope" request. (The API Guide contains info about these properties.)

Comment: As far as authentication is concerned, on [This page](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/Basic%20Scenarios/Creating%20an%20Envelope%20from%20a%20Document.htm) the note says you can store the baseurl and apiPassword. Would that mean the `X-DocuSign-Authentication` header is not needed in those requests where the apipassword is supplied? If so, can you supply a link to a page that goes into how to do that in more detail? If not, could you explain what the benefit of storing the apiPassword would be?

Comment: The X-DocuSign-Authentication header is required in each and every API request -- that's how DocuSign identifies the integrating application (and member account) and determines whether or not the request is authorized. The "login_information" request is used to retrieve info that's needed to build the X-DocuSign-Authentication header -- but since that info doesn't change often, the note is simply saying your app can make the "login_information" call once, then save/cache the info from the response, and simply re-use it to form the X-DocuSign-Authentication header for each subsequent request.

Comment: So every request to Docusign has to have a header that looks like: `<DocuSignCredentials><Username>username</Username><Password>password</Password><IntegratorKey>integratorKey</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>`?

Comment: Yes, every request to DocuSign has to contain the "Integrator Key" as well as authentication credentials (username, password, etc.). The X-DocuSign-Authentication header may look like what you've posted -- but could look somewhat different, depending on how you're authenticating the request (for example, using "Send-On-Behalf-Of" or using "oAuth" or using just regular authentication as you've shown in your prior comment.)

Comment: OK thats simple enough, but what is the purpose of the apiPassword that the documentation mentions?

Comment: apiPassword is simply the encrypted value of your password that can be retrieved with the login_information request (by setting a querystring parameter on the request URI: api_password=true).  If you don't want to send your plain-text password in the X-DocuSign-Authentication header, you can alternatively use the (encrpyted) apiPassword value -- either one will work to authenticate an API request.

Comment: OK I see what is meant by the documentation. Thanks for the info.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45947/discussion-between-mike-obrien-and-kim-brandl)

Comment: Used to be an acceptable answer, but DocuSign has changed and the URL doesn't even work anymore.  Mike's answer is currently up to date.